# Using Grep TO Scan Files

Tags: linux, grep, command

I need to use the grep command to scan all of the files in /etc for any occurrences of the word tcp in my Linux system.

How could I do this?

Comment: You can do it in different ways, but definitely by doing some research on `man grep` first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the unix site.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want "grep -r" for a recursive search of subdirectories.

i.e.: grep -r /etc/* tcp

Although, you probably aren't going to get very good information from such a search...

Answer (score 0):

try `grep --include=* -rnw /etc -e tcp`

searches all files under /etc recursively (-r) for the regex pattern (-e) "tcp" and gives you line numbers as well (-n), limited to whole words, though (-w)

Comment: I think it should be `--include=\*` (needs an escaped star), else it would be replaced with the working directory contents. Furthermore I think this option may be ommited in this case as everything should be the default.